# Remove links in the login block

Tags: 8, forms, users

I want to remove the following default links on the login block.

- Create new account
- Reset your password

I used `hook_form_alter()` but there is nothing in there that creates these links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method #1**

Implement *hook_preprocess_block()* in your module/theme.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function HOOK_preprocess_block__user_login_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['content']['user_links']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

**Method #2**

Override *block--user-login-block.html.twig* template and replace `{{ content }}` with the following `{{ content|without('user_links') }}`.

Note that hiding those links would not protect respective pages (*user/register* and *user/password*) from direct access.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to set proper permissions, because removing the links won't prevent users from typing `user/register` and `user/password` in the browser's address bar and reaching them directly.

However, if you really want to remove those links from the login block using the hook, then the following code should work:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_block') {
    unset($form['links']);
  }
}
```